# Examples of mobile frameworks that support AdSense for mobile content ads?

Tags: iphone, jqtouch, adsense, jquery-mobile, iui

I’ve tried, I *really* have, to find examples of serving up AdSense for mobile content ads in any of the popular mobile frameworks, but can’t find running webpages with ads, nor tutorials, etc....

I’ve done some iUI work, but would consider jQueryMobile, iWebKit, even sencha-touch if I could find an example that actually displays ads within the framework on an iPhone, iPod touch,etc...

I realize there are issues with the HTML adSense generates, but hasn’t anyone found a work-around? Surely some mobile HTML sites must be serving up ads?

Links to tutorials would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

AdSense is googles solution for the web as displayed on a desktop.

Admob is googles solution for the mobile web and mobile apps.

Use [Admob](http://www.admob.com/).

[Google Mobile Ads](http://www.google.com/mobileads/publisher_home.html).

Comment: Thanks Ben, I realized Google acquired AdMob a while back, and thought 'AdSense for mobile content' was Google's new name for it, but a search on "admob iUI" shows way more results, like the "iUI integration" section on http://developer.admob.com/wiki/IPhone but then also problems, like http://groups.google.com/group/iphonewebdev/browse_thread/thread/e9e74d153a407dbf